# Retain meshgrid structure when subsetting a meshgrid

Tags: matlab

When I subset an array constructed from `meshgrid`, I cannot work out how to keep its meshgrid structure. Thus, you cannot use it in a call to `mesh` or `surface`. I will demonstrate this in my example of constructing the unit sphere.

Possible alternate titles for this question:

1. How do you make the top half of the meshgrid sphere from scratch in Matlab?
2. How do you use mesh to plot a subset of a meshgrid?

This is motivated using the following toy example of constructing a sphere of unit radius in Matlab from scratch, so that it is like the one generated by:

```
[x, y, z] = sphere(100)
mesh(x, y, z)
```

Using the equation for a sphere:

[image: equation of sphere]

Define a meshgrid and `z` to be:

```
x = linspace(-1, 1, 201);
y = linspace(-1, 1, 201);
[x, y] = meshgrid(x, y);
z = sqrt(1 - x.^2 - y.^2);
```

So far so good, except `z` takes imaginary values where the sphere does not exist over the xy-plane, that is, anywhere outside of the unit circle.

A call to `mesh` now returns an error:

```
>> mesh(x, y, z)
Error using mesh (line 58)
X, Y, Z, and C cannot be complex.
```

Thus, a logical step is to remove all complex values:

```
% get logical vector index where real z is
LI = z == real(z)

x = x(LI)
y = y(LI)
z = z(LI)
```

But now `x`, `y`, and `z` are no longer 3d arrays, and calling `mesh` gives another error:

```
>> mesh(x, y, z)
Error using mesh (line 58)
Z must be a matrix, not a scalar or vector.
```

So, in general I have no idea how to preserve the `meshgrid` structure when subsetting the data. Hence, I can't generate the top half of this sphere from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you can "exclude" values from plotting while maintaining the matrix structure by using **NaN** value. In your case, try this:

```
LI = z == real(z);
z(~LI) = NaN;
mesh(x,y,z);
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I am running into another problem while trying to use `slice`: The coordinates of the input points must be finite values; Inf and NaN are not permitted.

Comment: Using NaN is not ideal in any case. So maybe you could have a look at this [link](http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/169373) to learn how to properly generate sphere using spherical coordinate phi and theta. To generate half sphere, I would modify the code in the link to `phi=linspace(0,pi/2,30);`

Comment: Unfortunately spherical coordinates does not help me with the data I have. Going back to the sphere example, I think it would be hard to get the surface formed by slicing the sphere using a diagonal plane. Conceptually the best way to do this is to use a subset, yet if you do a subset it ruins the grid structure.

Comment: The code from the link above begins with spherical data and then transform to x,y,z data, It produces the result pretty much the same as the `sphere` function. Anyway, when you use a subset, the new structure is indeed differ to the original, but you still can use that, eg. `m=10:100; mesh(x(m,m),y(m,m),z(m,m));` As for your problem with `slice` perhaps you should make a new question and give more detail.